# What does i.i.d. mean for multivariate case?

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, iid, multivariate-distribution

When we say a random variable is i.i.d., it's often used to describe the dependency between the observations of that random variable, which I call the row dimension, indexed by time if it's a time series.

What does i.i.d. mean when applied to multiple random variables at once? Does it mean that each separate r.v.'s observations are again i.i.d. observation-to-observation? or does it imply that all observations from r.v. 1 are i.i.d. from all the observations from r.v. 2, etc, etc? In other words, does the univariate definition of observation-to-observation change to one of distribution-to-distribution (individual distributions being independent from one another)?

Answer (score 7):

It usually means that the p-variate distribution of the vector rv $X_1$ is the same as that of $X_2$, $X_3$, ..., $X_n$ and that they're mutually independent.

It doesn't usually indicate anything about the independence nor identicality of distribution of the components of $ X_i$.

Usually if the discussion is about the components of $X_i$ there will be explicit/unambiguous reference to that fact.

Comment: so you're saying the univariate definition of i.i.d. that goes observation-by-observation *does* change to one of distribution-to-distribution

Comment: Sorry I don't follow what you're saying. Note that in the multivariate case, the "observation" is a vector of values, with some joint distribution.

Answer (score 1):

"When we say a random variable is i.i.d". No! 'We' don't say that. iid never refers to a single random variable, but always to a family/sequence (finite or infinite) of random variables $X_{1},X_{2},\dots$. And here actually one may rather speak of random elements than variables because this concept, i.e. identical distributions and independence, doesn't need at all the assumption of the $X_{i}$s being real-valued. They may also be vectors, functions, sets, (almost) whatever you like.

Comment: Using the term "variable" doesn't assume it is real-valued. There are also discrete or censored random variables, to name a few.

Comment: Discrete rv are in particular real valued. I don't know what censored r.v. are. But that wasn't the point anyway. Whatever we want to call it, the concept of iid is not restricted to real valued random entities.

Comment: Re "No!" I think this answer (which is not wrong, btw) might just be papering over the issue that troubled the OP: given any sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ of real-valued iid variables we may construct the *single* random variable $(X_1,X_2,\ldots)$ whose values are in a real vector space and in this sense, I suspect, many authors might freely (and even unconsciously) refer to it as an "iid" variable in the sense that its *marginals* are independent and identically distributed.